# Ruby - Accessing procedurally generated objects

Tags: ruby

**tldr: I am generating multiple similar objects at startup and want to be able to view, edit or otherwise manipulate each object. *How would you do this*?**

the program I'm writing records vehicle details (make, model, colour, description, manufacture date and a registration number). Previously I was generating the objects and dumping the data into a global variable which I then used to search, edit and save.

I am now trying to do away with this variable and interact directly with the objects.

All tutorials I have seen seem to rely on a hardcoded variable when initiating an object. For example

```
class Paragraph

attr_accessor :font, :size, :weight, :justification

end

p = Paragraph.new
p.font = 'Times'
p.size = 14
p.weight = 300
p.justification = 'right'

puts "#{p.font}, #{p.size}, #{p.weight}, #{p.justification}"
# => Times, 14, 300, right
```

so you can just use p.whatever to call each field. 
In my script I can't hardcode this as I have no idea how many objects are going to be created. This is the start of my script which loads previous records from a json and recreates the objects.

```
require 'json'

class Car
 attr_accessor :vrm
 attr_accessor :make
 attr_accessor :model
 attr_accessor :description
 attr_accessor :colour
 attr_accessor :date

def initialize(aMake, aModel, aDescription, aColour, aVRM, aManufactureDate)
  @vrm = aVRM
  @make = aMake
  @model = aModel
  @description = aDescription
  @colour = aColour
  @date = aManufactureDate
end

def text_format
  return "Vehicle details: Reg number #{@vrm}, Make #{@make}, Model #{@model}, Description #{@description}, Colour: #{@colour},  Date #{@date}"
end
end

def open_file
 if File.file?("vehicles.json")
   File.open('vehicles.json') do |f|
   $all_vehicles = JSON.parse(f.read)
 end
 $all_vehicles.each do |a_vehicle|
   Car.new(a_vehicle[1][0], a_vehicle[1][1], a_vehicle[1][3], a_vehicle[1][2], a_vehicle[0], a_vehicle[1][4])
  end
   count
   p $vehicle_id
 else
   p 'Unable to find file, creating blank file'
   save_to_file
 end
end
```

I can capture the object IDs in an array as it is created, but I can't see how to use that to call the object.

```
$all_vehicles.each do |a_vehicle|
  file << Car.new(a_vehicle[1][0], a_vehicle[1][1], a_vehicle[1][3], a_vehicle[1][2], a_vehicle[0], a_vehicle[1][4])
  $vehicle_id << file.object_id
end
```

I would like to do something like this

```
def search
list_vehicles = all Car objects

list_vehicles.each do |vehicle|
compare vehicle with search criteria

end
end
```

Comment: Did you consider using a `Hash` instead of an `Array` to store your instances? If you want to update the instances later on, how do you want to find the records? Is there something unique on each of the instances?

Comment: each vehicle gets a unique vehicle registration mark (vrm) so can be identified using that.  The array was simply to see if it would take the data, previously everything was stored in a hash with vrm as the key for each record. It worked perfectly but I don't feel having a giant global variable containing all my data is best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Hash` instead of an `Array` to store your instances and use the `vrm` as a key:

```
# initialize the hash
cars_by_vrm = {}

# when creating the instances
$all_vehicles.each do |a_vehicle|
  car = Car.new(a_vehicle[1][0], a_vehicle[1][1], a_vehicle[1][3], a_vehicle[1][2], a_vehicle[0], a_vehicle[1][4])
  cars_by_vrm[car.vrm] = car
end

# when you want to load a specific car later on
car = cars_by_vrm['some_vrm']
```

Note replace `cars_by_vrm` with a variable type or method that makes sense in your application.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I incorrectly assumed that pushing the object to hash would store it as string. Thank you.
I did vote, but my rep is too low to count.